# Use existing ionic Sass variables

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, sass

With Ionic 5, how can we use existing Sass Variables for our own css classes? The variables I mean are described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

I'd like to to something like this in global.scss:

```
.card-margin {
    margin-left: $card-md-margin-left;
    margin-right: $card-md-margin-right;
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot find where these variables are stored.

Comment: How do you include ionic in your project?

Comment: We just created an ionic project from scratch with "ionic start". Not sure what you need to know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4+ use CSS variables, so you can get it with the var(*variable*, *default?*) function.

e.g. for a background color, as defined in variables.scss :

```
background: var(--ion-color-light, #fff);
```

In Ionic 4+ there is no mention of a possible usage of the v3 sass variables. They are not available in the @angular/ionic module, we only have access to the final css.

You can still get them from the sources : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/tree/main/core/src/themes
and import them, but it seems a bit hacky.

Comment: I know you can use the variables from variables.scss like this. But I'm not able to use the values from the core ionic variables (Mentioned in the link from the original question). I tried like this:

variables.scss:
--ion-card-margin: $card-md-margin-left;

global.scss
.card-margin {
    margin-left: var(--ion-card-margin);
}

But it doesn't seem to find $card-md-margin-left in variables.scss.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it is not possible to get these variable values for Ionic v4+